# How to build debian transitional package without source code?

Tags: debian

Hello Debian Community,

I need to define a transitional package like [debian Renaming Packages Method](https://wiki.debian.org/RenamingPackages#Transition_package_method).

Since it is transitional it should not contain any actual source code, only pointing to the real package(via "Depends" field). The example from the official doc does not contain Source field too.

So I created a debian/control file like this:

```
Maintainer: Author
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.2
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9)

Package: transitional-deb-pkg
Depends: real-deb-pkg
Architecture: all
Description: transitional package
```

I did not create other debian files like debian/rules.

However, I got this error:

```
(dpkg-source: error: syntax error in debian/control at line 6: first block lacks a Source field)
```

Then I tried to rewrite debian/control file as below:

```
Source: source-code
Maintainer: Authors
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.2
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9)
Homepage: https://cloud.google.com/

Package: real-deb-pkg
Replaces: transitional-deb-pkg (<< 100.0.0~)
Breaks: transitional-deb-pkg (<< 100.0.0~)
Architecture: amd64 arm64
Description: real package

Package: transitional-deb-pkg
Depends: real-deb-pkg
Architecture: all
Description: transitional package
```

I am not sure if I need to add more debian files to make the build works.

Anyone know how to solve this or have prior experience building transitional package? Thank you!